# Retrieving comments for multiple posts in Rfacebook

Tags: r, facebook

I am using `getPost` to retrieve comments for posts, but is there anyway to do so for all posts?

The example provided is:

```
getPost(post=page$id[...], token, n = 500, comments = TRUE)
```

where `...` is the specific id of the Post.

Is there any way to retrieve comments for all Posts without having to iterate through each id of a Post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try the map() function from [purrr](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/purrr/versions/0.2.4/topics/map):

```
x <- map(pag_loop$id, getPost, token = fb_oauth, n = 5000)
```

Where `pag_loop$id`is a vector of posts' ids (retrieved by getPage), and the token in this case is the (temporary) user access token.

And then:

```
df_info_total <- do.call(rbind, x) #large matrix de 3*number_of_posts elementos
df_info_total <- bind_rows(df_info_total) #to get the total dataframe
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct function in the Rfacebook package to retrieve comments for posts. You will have to iterate through all the post ids and rbind their comments to get all the comments. You will have to do something like this:

```
i<-1
  df<-data.frame(from_id=numeric(),message=character(),....,id=numeric(),stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
    while(i<=nrow(posts)){
      comments<-getPost(post=posts$id[i],token=fb_oauth,n=500)[['comments']]
      df<-rbind(df,comments)
      i<-i+1
    }
```